# Are Method Attributes Inherited in C#?

Tags: c#, inheritance, attributes, methods

Are attributes applied to an abstract method in a base class applied to the overridden versions in the child classes?

I hope the question is clear enough without an example.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It depends on how the attribute itself is declared - see [`AttributeUsageAttribute.Inherited`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributeusageattribute.inherited.aspx) property.

Answer (score 17):

It depends on the Attribute.

attributes applied to Attribute class defination, carry a property [AttributeUsageAttribute.Inherited] that determines if an attributed is inherited in the derived classes.

check out this sample

```
[global::System.AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, 
     AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class MyAttribute : Attribute
{

    public MyAttribute (string FieldName)
    {
        //constructor.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can specify that by applying the [AttributeUsage attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw5zxet9(VS.100).aspx) to your custom ones, and setting the [Inherited property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributeusageattribute_properties(VS.71).aspx) (which is true by default). This property indicates if your attribute can be inherited by classes that are derived from the classes that have your custom attribute applied.

```
[AttributeUsage( Inherited = false)]
public class CustomAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

Recommended read:

- [Writing Custom Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84c42s56%28VS.100%29.aspx)