# Retrieve Attribute from an interface method

Tags: c#

How do I retrieve an attribute from an interface method my class implements?

Edit: I dont know the interface at the time, only the type of the class, or an instance of that class.

Edit: Added the inherited flag to the attribute but it has no effect.

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyTests {
    [Test]
    public void shouldGetMyAttribute() {
        var type = typeof (MyClass);
        var method = type.GetMethod("MyMethod");
        var attributes = method.GetCustomAttributes(true);
        var myAttribute = attributes.SingleOrDefault(x => x is MyAttributeAttribute);
        Assert.That(myAttribute, Is.Not.Null);
    }
}

public class MyClass : IMyInterface {
    public void MyMethod() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public interface IMyInterface {
    [MyAttribute]
    void MyMethod();
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class MyAttributeAttribute : Attribute {}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123563/are-method-attributes-inherited-in-c

Comment: Found this stating its a bug, but I dont know if that is correct still. its from '05.. http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/232588-interface-properties-custom-attributes

Comment: Still trying to come up with a workaround. I think I have to use something called InterfaceMapping using the GetInterfaceMap method, but havnt figured it out yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

typeof(MyClass).GetInterfaces() will return all interfaces implemented by the class. From there you can use code similar to what Ben M posted to navigate to the right method and attribute.

Comment: Please describe that in code.
From what I can gather, its not that easy. How do I match the method? I cant match by name or use Equals. I think I have to use something called InterfaceMapping using the GetInterfaceMap method, but havnt figured it out yet...